# How to resample DataFrame with MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to resample a dataframe with a MultiIndex and none of the questions on here seem to answer this question. I have a dataframe with a DateTimeIndex and another column as part of a MultiIndex. I am looking to resample this dataframe to a finer scale and fill the NaN values with forward fill. Here is what I thought would work:

```
arrays = [[dt.datetime(2020,10,2,1,0),dt.datetime(2020,10,2,1,0), dt.datetime(2020,10,2,2,0),dt.datetime(2020,10,2,2,0)] ,[1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ] ]

values = [i*i for i in range(0,4)]

df = pd.DataFrame(index = arrays ,data = values)
```

However, I get this error:

```
Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'MultiIndex'
```

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated

Comment: If you are trying to resample by a multi-index, and there is only one unique row per group, then you cannot resample... In other words, you have 0,1,2,3,4, but you would need more rows with more times. Esentially, you need at least two unique rows per group of you multiindex. If you only have one, how can you resample as you have to have a minimum and maximum to resample by your desired frequency.

Comment: For example, forgetting about the multi-index, then you wouldn't need to use a groupby and this code would work: `df = pd.DataFrame(index = dates, data = values)` and next line of code
`df1 = df.resample('5T').ffill()`

Comment: Sure , hold on on sec

Answer (score 0):

Keep your index as a single DatetimeIndex, then you can resample and recreate the index all you want:

```
dates = [dt.datetime(2020,10,2,i,0) for i in range(0,5)]
categories = [ i for i in range(0,5)]
values = [i*i for i in range(0,5)]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'cat': categories,
    'value': values
}, index=dates)

df = df.resample('5T').ffill().set_index('cat', append=True)
```

If your dataframe is the result of previous operations, remove all but the datetime from the index:

```
df = (
    df.reset_index(level=1)
      .resample('5T')
      .ffill()
      .set_index('cat', append=True)
)
```

Comment: My actual data has duplicate values in the DateTimeIndex part of the MultiIndex so I dont think this works

Comment: @KaneM can you update your sample data with what you mean by that?